# deep copy pointer of a struct object in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, deep-copy

I have a structure of the following type:

```
struct SPacket
{
    unsigned char payload[260]; 
    unsigned int payloadLength; 
};
```

I have a pointer object to this structure:

```
SPacket* ptrObj;
```

how can I perform a deep copy of ptrObj into a another object:

```
SPacket obj;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pointers - duplicate object instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050058/pointers-duplicate-object-instance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler-generated copy constructor will deep-copy the array member, so just use it:

```
SPacket obj(*ptrObj);
```

Comment: +1 but probably important to note, this is only correct for fixed size array's not allocated on the heap.

Comment: Error, no match for operator *

Comment: @jaycode: If you're receiving that error, you probably don't have a pointer :)

Comment: I can confirm. When the ptrObj is a reference (internally just a pointer) then there should be no asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is extremely simple: use the copy constructor:

```
SPacket obj = *ptrObj;
```

This will call the (implicit) copy constructor.

Comment: Thus would work in C too, no (after adding a `struct`)?

Comment: @juanchopanza I guess yes, it would. What I meant by the intro, is that the copy constructor should be the first thought

Comment: But the solution is also extremely simple in C.

Comment: @juanchopanza in this case, yes, it's the same. But if you have pointers inside the type you would need a copy/clone function.

Comment: Then you would have to implement a copy constructor in C++ anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK you win :p

Comment: Error, no match for operator *